# Analysis of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, asymptotics

I'm analysing function $$y=x+\frac{\ln x}{x}$$

and I kinda don't get few  parts. I get an oblique asymptote $y=x$, that function is increasing throughout the domain and that it is convex on $(e^\frac{3}{2}, \infty)$ and concave on $(0, e^\frac{3}{2})$

what bugs me is when i try to sketch a graph. It doesn't seem to match one on wolframalpha, particularly, it seems their is not convex on any part. One more thing, it also doesn't say function has an oblique asymptote.

Can anyone tell me how is wolfram getting those results?

Comment: the function is not defined (in the field of reals) for $x<0$

Comment: Wolfram alpha works in complex numbers by default, so you need to be careful with that.

Comment: thats my bad, ill edit

Comment: can you check if the right part of their graph is ok?

Comment: since $f''(x)<0 \quad \text{if}\,\, 0<x<e^{3/2} $ it is concave on this interval. for the rest of $\mathbb{R}_+$ it is convex

Comment: but the second derivative has a sign change somewhere right...?

Comment: @Sil how do you come up with that?

Comment: By having $x+log x$ in maple instead of $x+(log x)/x$... sorry, slow morning

Comment: @Sil no problem...so i finally edited the question how it is supposed to be...am I getting it right?

Comment: @StefanStipanovic Seems about right, also you will not see the function being convex in wolfram by default since it only draws graph for $x<3$. Also notice there is a combo button in the graph on top right, where you can switch to Real-valued plot, might be useful.

Comment: @Sil one more thing..when i plug in 1 i get 1, so it intersects the asymptote, and that is as far as i know not allowed. How can that happen?

Comment: @StefanStipanovic Asymptote describes the behaviour as you approach some point or infinity, in this case you have asymptote for $x\to \infty$. So what the function does at $x=1$ is not that much important, if it in a limit approaches the asymptote eventually. Anyway here it approaches its asymptote very fast, you can notice that for like $x>3$ you can barely distinguish it from $y=x$, and that is also why you dont see it being convex, but it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, and what is more, Wolfram alpha is also correct. The reason why you don't see the graph being convex is that it approaches its asymptote ($y=x$) rather quickly, so it is hardly distinguishable from straight line by just graph inspection. But at least that verifies that your asymptote is correct, you can draw the $y=x$ next to it for comparison (something like `plot x+log(x)/x and x from x = 0 to 10`).

Personally I would suggest to be careful when using Wolfram or other CAS systems and only use it to check your work, not to rely on it too much.